# subprocess.call() output won't change

Tags: python

I am trying to ping an IP using `subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '3','-w', '100', PingAddress])` but the output won't change from 0 or from 1. I am pinging a switch to see if it is online. If I am connected to it, it outputs 1 and so on. But if I am connected then disconnect it still outputs 1

```
ping = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '3','-w', '100', PingAddress])
while True:
    ping 
    print(ping)
    if ping != 0 and t < 3:
        t = t + 1
    elif ping == 0: #Success
        t = 0
        print(test)
    else:
        print(test)
        while True: 
            ping
            print(ping)
            if ping == 0:
                do stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ping = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '3','-w', '100', PingAddress])
while True:
    ping
```

You invoke [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) only once.  The `ping` variable's value is never again changed in this code.

Try this:

```
while True:
    ping = subprocess.call(['ping', '-n', '3','-w', '100', PingAddress])
    ...
```

Comment: Not sure if I am supposed to ask this, but why does the ping variable not call the code each time. How would I do that so it did. btw it did work.

Comment: Because `subprocess.call` _calls_ the subprocess and _returns_ its exit code.   `ping` is set to that return value.  It doesn't store the subprocess call, it stores the exit code of the subprocess call.   When you then say `ping` on a line,  there's no effect; same as `python -c "5"`